# Create a new field from already existing fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to create a new field from already existing fields in MongoDB

I have a document in my MongoDB that looks like this:

```json
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("63bfe39a6beaa01983fb3622"),
    "sourcemmsi": 228133000,
    "navigationalstatus": 15.0,
    "rateofturn": -127.0,
    "speedoverground": 10.6,
    "courseoverground": 258.3,
    "trueheading": 511,
    "lon": -4.7836165,
    "lat": 48.103264,
    "t": 1443656548
  }
```

I am trying to create a new field that would contain the fields lon,lat,t. In simply put, I am trying to create a nested field that would look like this:

```json
 {
    "_id": ObjectId("63bfe39a6beaa01983fb3622"),
    "sourcemmsi": 228133000,
    "navigationalstatus": 15.0,
    "rateofturn": -127.0,
    "speedoverground": 10.6,
    "courseoverground": 258.3,
    "trueheading": 511,
    "position": {
      "lat": 48.103264,
      "lon": -4.7836165,
      "t": 1.443656548e+09
    },
  }
```

Is there any was I can accomplish that?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Simply do a `$project` in the aggregation pipeline in `update`

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$project": {
      "sourcemmsi": 1,
      "navigationalstatus": 1,
      "rateofturn": 1,
      "speedoverground": 1,
      "courseoverground": 1,
      "trueheading": 1,
      "position": {
        "lon": "$lon",
        "lat": "$lat",
        "t": "$t"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CcZBAfBKf1M)